# HTTP errors priority

Tags: http, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-400

I am building RESTful API and my understanding of good approaches is getting better. Now, I have a following question:

Let's say I have a PUT request to /movies/15, which is updating the movie. The request is invalid, because it doesn't contain update data and movie with id of 15 doesn't exist. Which error status should be returned? `404` for missing movie or `400` for missing data?

My intuition tells me that it should be `404`, because I feel like the URL part is the most important. Am I right?